# Reshape wide to long for many columns with a common prefix

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My frame has many pairs of identically named columns, with the only difference being the prefix. For example, `player1.player.id` and `player2.player.id`.

Here's an example (with fewer and shorter columns):

```
pd.DataFrame({'p1.a': {0: 4, 1: 0}, 'p1.b': {0: 1, 1: 4},
              'p1.c': {0: 2, 1: 8}, 'p1.d': {0: 3, 1: 12},
              'p1.e': {0: 4, 1: 16}, 'p1.f': {0: 5, 1: 20},
              'p1.g': {0: 6, 1: 24},
              'p2.a': {0: 0, 1: 0}, 'p2.b': {0: 3, 1: 12},
              'p2.c': {0: 6, 1: 24}, 'p2.d': {0: 9, 1: 36},
              'p2.e': {0: 12, 1: 48}, 'p2.f': {0: 15, 1: 60},
              'p2.g': {0: 18, 1: 72}})

   p1.a  p1.b  p1.c  p1.d  p1.e  p1.f  p1.g  p2.a  p2.b  p2.c  p2.d  p2.e  p2.f  p2.g
0     4     1     2     3     4     5     6     0     3     6     9    12    15    18
1     0     4     8    12    16    20    24     0    12    24    36    48    60    72
```

I'd like to turn it into a long format, with a new `side` column denoting either `p1` or `p2`. I have several crappy ways of doing it, for example:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^p1.*').assign(side='p1')
df2 = df.filter(regex='^p2.*').assign(side='p2')
df1.columns = [c.replace('p1.', '') for c in df1.columns]
df2.columns = [c.replace('p2.', '') for c in df2.columns]
pd.concat([df1, df2]).head()

   a   b   c   d   e   f   g side
0  4   1   2   3   4   5   6   p1
1  0   4   8  12  16  20  24   p1
0  0   3   6   9  12  15  18   p2
1  0  12  24  36  48  60  72   p2
```

This feels non-idiomatic, and I couldn't get `pd.wide_to_long()` to work here.

I'd appreciate an answer which also handles *arbitrary substrings*, not just *prefix*, i.e., I'm also interested in something like this:

```
   foo.p1.a  foo.p1.b  foo.p1.c  foo.p1.d  foo.p1.e  foo.p1.f  foo.p1.g  foo.p2.a  foo.p2.b  foo.p2.c  foo.p2.d  foo.p2.e  foo.p2.f  foo.p2.g
0         4         1         2         3         4         5         6         0         3         6         9        12        15        18
1         0         4         8        12        16        20        24         0        12        24        36        48        60        72
```

Turning into:

```
   foo.a  foo.b  foo.c  foo.d  foo.e  foo.f  foo.g side
0      4      1      2      3      4      5      6   p1
1      0      4      8     12     16     20     24   p1
0      0      3      6      9     12     15     18   p2
1      0     12     24     36     48     60     72   p2
```

But if there's an idiomatic way to handle prefixes whereas substrings require complexity, I'd appreciate learning about both.

What's the idiomatic (pythonic? pandonic?) way of doing this?

Comment: can you provide a clean, reproducible example with expected output. You can then adapt it to your actual data

Comment: @sammywemmy hope this is better?

Comment: more like it @yanivaknin; i'll scribble a solution now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options to do this:

with [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), you need to reorder the positions based on the delimiter; in this case we move the `a`, `b`, ... to the fore and the `p1`, `p2` to the back, before reshaping:

```
temp = df.copy()
temp = temp.rename(columns = lambda df: ".".join(df.split(".")[::-1]))
(pd.wide_to_long(temp.reset_index(), 
                 stubnames = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], 
                 sep=".", 
                 suffix=".+", 
                 i = "index", 
                 j = "side")
  .droplevel('index')
  .reset_index()

  side  a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   p1  4   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   p1  0   4   8  12  16  20  24
2   p2  0   3   6   9  12  15  18
3   p2  0  12  24  36  48  60  72
```

One limitation with [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) is the reshaping of positions. The other limitation is that the stubnames have to be explicitly specified.

Another option is via [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack), where the columns are split, based on the delimiter and reshaped:

```
temp = df.copy()
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(".", expand = True)

temp.stack(0).droplevel(0).rename_axis('side').reset_index()

  side  a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   p1  4   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   p2  0   3   6   9  12  15  18
2   p1  0   4   8  12  16  20  24
3   p2  0  12  24  36  48  60  72
```

[stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) is quite flexible, and did not require us to list the column names. The limitation of [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) is that it fails if the index is not unique.

Another option is [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which abstracts the process:

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(index = None, 
                names_to = ("side", ".value"), 
                names_sep=".")
 
  side  a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   p1  4   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   p1  0   4   8  12  16  20  24
2   p2  0   3   6   9  12  15  18
3   p2  0  12  24  36  48  60  72
```

The *worker* here is `.value`. This tells the code that anything after `.` should remain as column names, while anything before `.` should be collated into a new column (`side`). Note that, unlike `wide_to_long`, the stubnames do not need to be stated - it abstracts that for us. Also, it can handle duplicate indices, since it uses `pd.melt` under the hood.
One limitation of `pivot_longer` is that you have to install the [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) library.

For the other example, I'll use  [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) and [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer); you can still use [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to solve it.

With [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack):

first split the columns and convert into a MultiIndex:

```
temp = df.copy()
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(".", expand = True)
```

Reshape the data:

```
temp = temp.stack(1).droplevel(0).rename_axis('side')
```

Merge the column names:

```
temp.columns = temp.columns.map(".".join)
```

Reset the index:

```
temp.reset_index()

  side  foo.a  foo.b  foo.c  foo.d  foo.e  foo.f  foo.g
0   p1      4      1      2      3      4      5      6
1   p2      0      3      6      9     12     15     18
2   p1      0      4      8     12     16     20     24
3   p2      0     12     24     36     48     60     72
```

With [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer), one option is to reorder the columns, before reshaping:

```py
temp = df.copy()

temp.columns = ["".join([first, last, middle]) 
                for first, middle, last in 
                temp.columns.str.split(r'(\.p\d)')]

(
temp
.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('.value', 'side'), 
    names_pattern = r"(.+)\.(p\d)")
)
  side  foo.a  foo.b  foo.c  foo.d  foo.e  foo.f  foo.g
0   p1      4      1      2      3      4      5      6
1   p1      0      4      8     12     16     20     24
2   p2      0      3      6      9     12     15     18
3   p2      0     12     24     36     48     60     72
```

In the [dev](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor) version however, the column reorder is not necessary; we can simply use multiple `.value` to reshape the dataframe - note that you'll have to install from the repo to get the latest dev version:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('.value', 'side', '.value'), 
    names_pattern = r"(.+)\.(.\d)(.+)")
)
  side  foo.a  foo.b  foo.c  foo.d  foo.e  foo.f  foo.g
0   p1      4      1      2      3      4      5      6
1   p1      0      4      8     12     16     20     24
2   p2      0      3      6      9     12     15     18
3   p2      0     12     24     36     48     60     72
```

Another option with `names_sep`:

```py
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('.value', 'side', '.value'), 
    names_sep = r'\.(p\d)')
)
  side  foo.a  foo.b  foo.c  foo.d  foo.e  foo.f  foo.g
0   p1      4      1      2      3      4      5      6
1   p1      0      4      8     12     16     20     24
2   p2      0      3      6      9     12     15     18
3   p2      0     12     24     36     48     60     72
```

Comment: Wow, thank you @sammywemmy! I'm surprised this seems quite difficult. Perhaps the problem is that my columns aren't named well? Would you say it's more idiomatic to ensure my dataframe always have the "wide variable" as a suffix, like a.foo, b.foo, c.foo insetad of foo.a, foo.b, foo.c? (this can get quite long, e.g.: `player.faf_rating.bucket.player1`)

Comment: you could ensure that it is either a prefix or suffix, and then reshape either with `pivot_longer` or use `stack`. If you are going to use `wide_to_long` then suffix is preferable. Also note that with `stack` and `wide_to_long`, you have to look out for duplicate indices(I assume your data does not have this issue); `pivot_longer` can safely handle duplicate indices.

Comment: No duplicate indices before `wide_to_long`, but I think after calling it I will have created two rows for every index...?

Comment: @YanivAknin yes, for every index you should have more than one row