# In Pandas how could I pivot select date columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a rather annoying csv file in which date columns need to move into rows using python using pandas.

Here is how the original source csv file looks (note there is actually 208 sales and volume columns covering two years of weekly data):

| ProductID | StoreID | 24/06/2019_Sales | 01/07/2019_Sales | 24/06/2019_Vol | 01/07/2019_Vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 230 | 15.00 | 20.00 | 3 | 5 |
| 8 | 179 | 7.00 | 14.00 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 54 | 20.00 | 10.00 | 2 | 1 |

And what I am trying to obtain is:

| ProductID | StoreID | Date. | Sales | Vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 230 | 01/07/2019 | 15.00 | 3 |
| 8 | 179 | 01/07/2019 | 7.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 54 | 01/07/2019 | 20.00 | 2 |
| 1 | 230 | 24/06/2019 | 20.00 | 5 |
| 8 | 179 | 24/06/2019 | 14.00 | 2 |
| 1 | 54 | 24/06/2019 | 10.00 | 1 |

I have tried using the melt function but I am not getting much luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think there are a couple of solutions on StackOverflow that addresses this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67393474/reshape-wide-to-long-for-many-columns-with-a-common-prefix/67393747#67393747)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I may have partly solved it myself with the following code:

```
df2 = df.melt(['ProductID', 'StoreID'], var_name='Date', value_name='Measure')
df2[['Misc','Date']] = df2['Date'].str.split('_',expand=True)
```

I will then merge the records. Open to any further feedback.

Comment: Thanks Henry I am new to this platform